# Solve the memory management problems by proving program correctness like with coq?

Tags: memory-management, programming-languages, language-design, type-systems, proof-of-correctness

I just wanted to ask if it would be possible to construct a language with a type system that can solve the memory management problems (memory leaks, dangling pointers, double `free()`, etc.) by automatically trying to prove the correctness of any program with its types as propositions like with an integrated coq-like theorem prover (in the mindset of programs as proofs)?

Is there a fundamental logical problem to this approach (halting problem maybe?) or is it just unfeasible? Thanks for any answers and I'm sorry that I'm not so well-versed in this field, just want to know out of curiosity ;)

Comment: Yes, by never allowing programmers direct access to pointers. A similar thing is done in Linux with the `ln` command. Regular users cannot use it to link directories. Directories can only be made with the `mkdir` command. This prevents memory-management problems of the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there has been a lot of research into languages that do compile-time memory management. Rust and its ownership model is the most high profile industry language in this area. You might always want to look into "[linear types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system)".

Comment: But is there a way to completely remove the responsibility from the programmer while solving the problem compile-time? As I have heard, fighting with the borrow checker in Rust can be quite exhausting. And linear type systems seem to me a bit limited, for example persistent data structures would be impossible.